# how to create dynamic html in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I want to create accordion in angular2 i don't want to repeat the structure of accordion(just want to create once and call the structure) and used in whole application how can we do this Like in jquery we create plugin and embed html but how can we do this with angular2

Comment: Check out their tutorial https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3. Follow the `hero-detail` component tutorial.

Comment: You're looking for a directive: https://angular.io/api/core/Directive

Comment: if you want a accordion behavior and a dynamic html content it's sadly not really possible easily (unlike in react). You can define some templates and switch it in function of your source

Answer (score 0):

One way, is to **use ["Angular powered Bootstrap"](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home).** You can find the installation guide [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started).

This project contains [open-source](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tree/master/src) Angular components that wrap the html and css of bootstrap components. It results in html-tags that start with a `<ngb-...` prefix.

Here follows an example that I just made up. Let's say we create our own `TopicTreeComponent` to visualize `Topic` instances in an accordion.

For the sake of this example let's say you have a `Topic` class.

```
export class Topic
{
  public title;
  public text;
  ...
}
```

You would need a `TopicTreeComponent` class that shows these components.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'topic-tree',
  templateUrl: './topictree.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./topictree.component.css']})
export class TopicTreeComponent
{
  public topics: Topic[] = ... ;
}
```

Then the view of your `TopicTreeComponent` could look something like this:

```
<nav>
  <ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion"
    activeIds="ngb-panel-0"
    closeOthers="true">

    <ngb-panel *ngFor="let topic of topics">
      <ng-template ngbPanelTitle class="bg-inverse">
          {{topic.title}}
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
          {{topic.text}}
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-panel>

  </ngb-accordion>
</nav>
```

It iterates the topics of your class, and shows the title and text.

This example uses the `NgbAccordion` component, which is documented [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/api).